# XSLT transformation adding unwanted Linefeed

Tags: whitespace, xslt, transformation, carriage-return, linefeed

Using Vs 2010 I am editing a xsl file which will be used for transformation to output an xml file. I am trying to output a carriage return () and that only. I don't want the linefeed character (x0A) to appear.

No matter what kind of stunt I do in the xsl, the outputted file always adds a LF to my CR (CRLF) and I don't want that. The reason for why I want only the CR is that the output is parsed by a secondary system that sends sms-messages, which requires only LF.

I'm wondering if the problem is in the xsl or the transformation process.

The stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:l="http://schemas.something.no/2008/" version='1.0'>
 <xsl:import href='LydiaDateFuncs.xsl'/>
 <xsl:template match='/'>
   <xsl:apply-imports/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no" />

 <xsl:template match="l:WorkOrderOccurrenceBE">
   <Message>
     <Body>
       Adding cr here<xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>No dice.
     </Body>
   </Message>
 </xsl:template>
```

The code for transformation:

```
public static XmlDocument TransformObject(string xslFilepath, object serObj) 
{
XmlDocument result = null;
xslTransf.Load(xslFilepath, new XsltSettings { EnableScript = true }, newXmlUrlResolver());
result = TransformObject(xslTransf, serObj);
}

public static XmlDocument TransformObject(XslCompiledTransform xslTransform, object transformObject)
{
    XmlDocument result = null;
    if (xslTransform != null)
    {
        DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(transformObject.GetType());

        string serializedObjValue = null;
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(stream, transformObject);
            serializedObjValue = (new UTF8Encoding()).GetString(stream.ToArray());
        }

        if (serializedObjValue != null)
        {
            XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmldoc.LoadXml(serializedObjValue);

            XmlDeclaration xmldec = xmldoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null);
            xmldoc.InsertBefore(xmldec, xmldoc.DocumentElement);

            using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                xslTransform.Transform(xmldoc, null, stream);
                stream.Position = 0;
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.Unicode))
                {
                    string xmlRes = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    result = new XmlDocument();
                    result.LoadXml(xmlRes);
                }
            } 
        }  
    }
    return result;
}
```

Anybody been experiencing a similar issue?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a detailed solution and links to the appropriate MSDN documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this problem is to use an `XmlTextWriter` in a respective overload of `XslCompiledTransform.Transform()`

This instnce of `XmlTextWriter` must have its `Settings` property set with an instance of `XmlWriterSettings` for which you have specified whatever newline characters you want as the value of the `XmlWriterSettings.NewLineChars` property.

See:  **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.settings.aspx**

and

**http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.newlinechars.aspx**

Comment: Okey, thanks. I'll see if I can rewrite this specific section using an XmlTextWriter. I'll run it through the head developer.